# how to select all by highest from a table where the value of a column does not reapet

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select row by the highest votecount from a table, but if the userid is repeted i want the just the row with the highest votecount. eg:

| userId | votecount |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 1 | 20 |

my result is supposed to be:

```
1,20
2,12
```

this is my current code:

```
SELECT * from `audio` GROUP BY `userId` ORDER BY `votecount` DESC LIMIT 50
```

the result of my code is :

```
1,20
2,2
```

it's  grouping by userId and then ordering it by votecount, which is not the desired output

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: i'm using mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
select `userid`, MAX(`votecount`)
FROM `audio`
GROUP BY `userId` ORDER BY `votecount`
```

Comment: this just gets the highest votecount but not the correct row, if i edit this query to : `SELECT date,votecount,promoted,status,image,name,id,userId, MAX(votecount) FROM audio GROUP BY userId ORDER BY votecount;`

it gets the first row with the userId and just replaces the votecount with the highest votecount

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case and you don't have a unique row id, you need to add the other columns in the group by clause

```
SELECT date, promoted, status, image, name, id, userId, MAX(votecount)  
FROM audio 
GROUP BY date, promoted, status, image, name, id, userId
ORDER BY votecount DESC
```

Comment: the userid  repeats somtimes, so i want the row with the highest votecount of that particular userid